# Is there any plug-in that edit another job's option?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to edit other job's option by executing some job.
It means that when job 'A' is executing, I want job 'A' edit job "B's option". Like poll SCM.
Is it possible?

I tried google and chat gpt but I can't find solution.

Comment: will require script approval, but possible. will need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60640249/6727228

Comment: thxs. I wonder it works even general freestyle job. Not pipeline job.